# Ubuntu Server 22.04 can only see one IronWolf 4TB drive, after installing a second

Tags: server, zfs, sata

My 6 disk ZFS array had a drive go out the other day. It was built on all HGST 2TB DeskStar HDDs. I decided I would slowly double the size of the all drives after replacing the first one, and eventually rebuild the array once I had replaced all the 2TB HGSTS drives with 4TB Seagate IronWolf drives.

I replaced the bad HGST drive with a 4TB IronWolf CMR drive and the pool rebuilt itself fine (Yes I know the sector size isn't right, but I need storage, not performance for now). I am now trying to replace another drive with another 4TB IronWolf but Ubuntu doesn't see it.

If I run `sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep ata-ST4*` I only see the first drive I put in the array. No other IronWolf drives show up.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 11 20:17 ata-ST4000VN008-2DR166_ZDHBWL39 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 20:17 ata-ST4000VN008-2DR166_ZDHBWL39-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 11 20:17 ata-ST4000VN008-2DR166_ZDHBWL39-part9 -> ../../sde9
```

Running `sudo lsblk|grep disk` with 2 IronWolf drives I get:

```
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
sdb           8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
sdc           8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
sdd           8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk
sde           8:64   1   3.6T  0 disk
sdf           8:80   1   1.8T  0 disk
sdg           8:96   1   1.8T  0 disk
sdh           8:112  1   1.8T  0 disk
sdi           8:128  1   1.8T  0 disk
sdj           8:144  0 111.8G  0 disk
```

When I take the second IronWolf out and run `sudo lsblk|grep disk` I see:

```
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
sdb           8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
sdc           8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
sdd           8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk
sde           8:64   1   3.6T  0 disk
sdf           8:80   1   1.8T  0 disk
sdg           8:96   1   1.8T  0 disk
sdh           8:112  1   1.8T  0 disk
sdi           8:128  1   1.8T  0 disk
sdj           8:144  1   1.8T  0 disk
sdk           8:160  0 111.8G  0 disk
```

Why would Ubuntu be unable to see that second IronWolf drive?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't think of this sooner, but I have a USB HDD dock. I hooked it up to my main Windows computer so I could see if Windows could see either of the two remaining drives. Windows unable to see one of them at all, and the other one was visible but Windows was unable to create a partition table on it. Based on that it was pretty obvious that both drives were bad.

I've avoided Seagate drives for years, and after deciding to give them a try again, 2 out of the 3 I bought were defective. Not good reintroduction to Seagate...